# What command can allow me to recreate the django_admin_log table?

Tags: django, django-migrations

I deleted that table (whoops), and now I'd like to regenerate it. Is there a command that allows me to do that? Looking online, everyone is saying to use the command `./manage.py syncdb`, but that command is no longer available in the most recent version of Django. So I tried `./manage.py migrate`, but that didn't generate the table. I also tried `./manage.py --run-syncdb`, but that didn't do it either.

I'm pretty sure I can do it by hand, but I'm hoping there's a way to do this with a built-in command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the admin app only has one table, `django_admin_log`, you can revert all migrations for the admin app by running

`python manage.py migrate admin zero`

then re-apply the the admin app migrations by running

`python manage.py migrate`

You might want to create a backup before doing this (or any migration, really) :)

Comment: The first command results in the same error I got before, namely `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: django_admin_log`.

Comment: Also, thanks for the suggestion. Yeah this is not the best practice, but it's all in the debugging state at this point. Just trying to learn (and hopefully document for other people) what to do in this situation when it happens with live data.

Comment: if you deleted the table outside of the normal migration process, you may need to fake the migration backwards. Try `python manage.py migrate admin zero --fake` followed by `python manage.py migrate`